# Implementing Path-Level Routing for Domain Redirect to AWS EC2 Instance

Tags: angular, spring-boot, amazon-ec2, dns, google-sites

Title:
Implementing Path-Level Routing for Domain Redirect to AWS EC2 Instance

Body:

I am encountering an issue with path-level routing during a domain redirection process and would appreciate guidance on potential solutions.
Context:
Primary Domain: [www.dummyexample.us](http://www.dummyexample.us)
Developed using Google Sites.
Hosted on Google's servers.
Secondary Web Application:
Backend: Spring Boot.
Frontend: Angular.
Hosted on an AWS EC2 instance.

Issue:

When users click the "Login" button on [www.dummyexample.us](http://www.dummyexample.us), they are redirected to the secondary web application hosted on the AWS EC2 instance. Post-redirection, the URL displayed in the browser is that of the EC2 instance (e.g., ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.compute-1.amazonaws.com). My objective is to retain the primary domain in the URL post-redirection, aiming for something like [www.dummyexample.us/login](http://www.dummyexample.us/login).

Attempted Solutions:

Modified DNS records in Google Domains for [www.dummyexample.us](http://www.dummyexample.us).
Adjusted the DNS records in AWS Route 53.
Unfortunately, neither approach yielded the desired outcome.

Constraints:

Utilizing a reverse proxy is not feasible as I lack access to the configuration file of the web server where [www.dummyexample.us](http://www.dummyexample.us) is hosted.

Request:

Could anyone suggest alternative methods or strategies to achieve this URL path-level routing? Any insights or recommendations would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: A reverse proxy of some sort is the only way you can achieve two (or more) separate servers hosting content for a single domain name. A CDN like Google Cloud CDN, AWS CloudFront, or Cloudflare would work as a reverse-proxy here, enabling you to point different paths to different back-end origin servers. Otherwise you need to change your design to use a different subdomain for the EC2 instance, like `app.dummyexample.us`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. We tried the subdomain thing that you suggested, but that too didn't work. We created an A record, and in the IP address field we gave the public IP address of our EC2 instance. But that was in vain. Can you please suggest any other thing that could work?

Comment: Just saying "we tried it, and it didn't work" is not helpful. You need to explain what exactly didn't work. Was there some sort of error or something? Creating an A record, pointing at the public IP, is the correct way to setup the DNS.

Comment: I'm sorry for being lame. It wasn't getting routed to the EC2 instance when i enter the URL of the subdomain in the browser(app.dummyexample.us). So we are approaching it from a different perspective now. Thank you sir. I am extremely grateful for your assistance.

Comment: Maybe you just didn't wait long enough for the DNS to propagate.